# Endianness and hexdump of text file

Tags: hardware, endianness

My computer has an x86-64 processor and runs linux.

I created a textfile called with the following characters: `abcde` (a new line would have been put at the end too)

I ran a hexdump on this file and got:

```
0000000 6261 6463 0a65                         
0000006
```

The order of the bytes suggests that the text was stored as `badc\ne`. Why is this? Is this related to endianness? Why is the order changed within two-byte blocks, but not overall? I could understand this if my computer had a 16 bit word length, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Endianness does not affect byte order in files. What you are seeing is some artefact of your hexdump program.

Comment: what do you mean by artefact?